# Not rendering react chart js in production after saving the data from grapesJs editor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, grapesjs

Looking for help... I have created a custom block of charts from `chartjs` in `grapesjs` and added script to load in `grapesjs` canvas editor but when I'm saving its HTML to render it on the production page. All HTML portions with style are rendered successfully but chart components are not rendering. I haven't any idea to deal with it. could you please help me? I am stuck for 10 days Please help me

used method:

`editor.getProjectData()` -> to get editor data
`editor.loadProjectData()` -> to load data in production

even I have tried

1. `getHtml()`,
2. `setComponents` nothing works for me